# Python - Subtracting a value from an array based on input

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
product = [['p3','p5','p7'], ['16GB','32GB'],['1TB','2TB'], ['19in','23in'], ['Mini Tower', 'Midi Tower'], ['2 ports','4 ports']]
stock = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
chosen = []
for part in product:
  for i in part:
    if input('Would you like the following component: '+i) == 'y':
      print("Selected: ", i)
      chosen.append(i)
      position = product[part].index(chosen)
      stock -= stock[position]
      print(stock)
      break
```

I'm having a problem defining 'position', the aim of the variable is to find the position of the input (eg. p3) and then apply that to subtracting the corresponding stock value. 
Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this? Much appreciated.

Comment: do you want `enumerate`?

Answer (score -1):

Basically it is like 2D array:

try like this.

In Python we can write like for any 2D array.

```
for i in range(len(product)):
    for j in range(len(product[i])):
        print(product[i][j],i,j)
```

Note: Your code has lot of errors , I am just stating how to access and get the location of an array variable in python

Comment: I don't think this answers the question